# Django Auth user date_joined field datetime to string

Tags: python, django, datetime

When i am fetching the stored datetime value from auth user in django the value comes as below is there a way to convert this into normal date time format may be like `"dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss"`  or some string value that can be displayed in better(other) format

```
 date_joined = request.user.date_joined
 #date_joined value is 
 #datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 11, 16, 6, 22, 314637, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format a datetime object using its [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) method, for example like this:

```
 date_joined = request.user.date_joined
 date_joined.strftime("%d:%m:%y %H:M:S")
```

If you want to display a datetime object in Django template, you can use the builtin [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter.

```
{{ date_joined|date:"d:m:Y H:i:s")
```